# Atlassian Bitbucket (Stash) SSL certificate renewal

Tags: ssl-certificate, bitbucket, bitbucket-server

So we have a self-hosted version of Atlassian BitBucket running on Ubuntu server which holds the code repository. We use a SSL certificate from DigiCert . Every year we renew the certificate which has never caused issues. However this time most of the developers are getting the following error when pushing and pulling code from GIT after the certificate was renewed

> fatal: unable to access : SSL certificate problem: unable to get local
>   issuer certificate

Another Error:

> fatal: unable to access : Peer's Certificate issuer is not
>   recognized.

However, when we try to access the website using Chrome (or any other browser), it works fine and there is no error

All searches online point to this error when you're using a self-signed or internal PKI certificate. We are totally stumped on why a certificate issued by a public authority like DigiCert is getting this error.

Any help on this would be highly appreciated.

Comment: change ssl verification as false for time being `git config --global http.sslVerify false`

Answer (score 0):

1. Ensure the root cert is added to git.exe's certificate store as discussed [here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/phkelley/2014/01/20/adding-a-corporate-or-self-signed-certificate-authority-to-git-exes-store/).
2. Tell Git where to find the CA bundle by running:

   git config --system http.sslCAPath /absolute/path/to/git/certificates

or copying the CA bundle to the /bin directory and adding the following to the gitconfig file:

```
sslCAinfo = /bin/curl-ca-bundle.crt
```

3. Reinstalling Git.
4. Ensuring that the complete CA is present, including the root cert.

   Check [www.atlassian.com](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucketserverkb/resolving-ssl-self-signed-certificate-errors-806029899.html) more ssl errors for resolutions.